# calcular años en django

Tags: python, django

hola estoy intentando calcular la edad de una persona tomando los datos de nacimiento "nacdate" de un modelo Pacientes. Pero no me hayo como rendeerizarlo. ya hice  pruebas con puro python y funciona.

**calcular_años.py**

```
from datetime import date

def calcular_años(fecha_naciento):
    fecha_actual = date.today()
    resultado = fecha_actual.year - fecha_naciento.year
    # esta re asicnacion a resultado nos comprueba la edad exacta contando los meses
    resultado -= ((fecha_actual.month, fecha_actual.day) < (fecha_naciento.month, 
fecha_naciento.day))
    return resultado

fecha_nacimiento_sebas = date(1993, 9, 16 )
edad = calcular_años(fecha_nacimiento_sebas)

print(f'la edad de sebas es {edad}')
```

y tengo la duda de que si la funcion la debo pasar a la view o al model de django. Lo puse en la view asi.

```
class paciente_años(CreateView):
model = Pacientes
template_name = 'core/paciente_detail.html'

def Calcular_Años(self, nacdate):
    birth_day = date(nacdate)
    fecha_actual = date.today()
    resultado = fecha_actual.year - birth_day.year
   
    return resultado
```

No se como tomar esos datos del modelfield "nacdate" y poderlos meter a una funcion y luego renderizarla en el template que esta asi. Asi pues solo e muestra la fecha de nacimiento.

```
{{pacientes.nacdate}}
```

Dejo mi model si ayuda en algo.

```
class Pacientes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Nombre')
    cedula = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Cedula')
    phone = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Telefono')
    nacdate = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha de nacimiento')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', verbose_name='Foto del paciente')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Es buena práctica seguir el principio de "modelos gordos y vistas flacas", o sea, tratar de colocar toda la lógica en los modelos.

```
class Pacientes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Nombre')
    cedula = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Cedula')
    phone = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Telefono')
    nacdate = models.DateField(verbose_name='Fecha de nacimiento')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', verbose_name='Foto del paciente')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def calcular_años(self):
        return date.today().year - self.nacdate.year
```